# Flex Flexbox, Push right, Align Left and different widths

Tags: css, flexbox, right-to-left

left side Easy, is done.

but what about right section RESPONSIVE PUSHED right but align left, small box included.. see the image:

Any flexbox easy idea?
[image]

Comment: You need to provide a working code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.left {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.wide {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box wide"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="box wide"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Valentin you really need to provide more information.  You could use `width: 50%` you could use `flex-grow: 0`.  What width is it you are looking to achieve?  The width of the content?